# How can a telegram bot change that works only for a specific time in a group?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm built a telegram bot for the groups.When the bot is added to the group, it will delete messages containing ads.How can I change the bot to work for only 30 days in each group and then stop it?
That means, for example, today's bot is added to group 1 and the next week the bot is added to group 2; I need to change the bot to stop the 30 days in group 1 and stop it in group 2 for another 37 days.
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a telegram bot that only works for 30 days per user and then stops there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194007/how-to-create-a-telegram-bot-that-only-works-for-30-days-per-user-and-then-stops)

Answer (score 0):

You can't know how long your bot had been added to group at this time. :(

You need to log it to your own database, and there is `leaveChat` method if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, all you need is a database at the back-end. Just store the `group_id` and `join_date` in each row.

At any time, you can query your database. If more than 30 days has passed `join_date`, stop the bot or leave the group.

You can also use any other storage rather than a database. A file, index, etc.